# ERROR : The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to launch 'tns doctor' but I still have an error

> "The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set ".

When I : `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` I have : `C:\Users\lno\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

That's the good path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `ANDROID_HOME` to your PC's environment variables.

Navigate to This PC and select `properties > System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables.`

Once you are there click on the New button below User Variables and type`ANDROID_HOME` into the name field, and your `sdk path`(in your case : `C:\Users\lno\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`) into the Variable Value field.

You need to restart your machine for it to work!